# How to add NFC pairing capability of Bluetooth headphones to Windows 10 laptop?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, headphones, nfc

I have Bluetooth headphones that I pair to my smartphone via NFC.

I want to do the same with my laptop but don't have NFC in it.

I can buy a USB-NFC reader, but not sure if I get the same functionality on my Windows 10 laptop.

Anyone has an experience with it and can say whether it's possible, and if so how?

Comment: Just purchase a USB Bluetooth device that supports pairing Bluetooth devices over NFC.

Comment: Actually not that simple - there's a couple of things that need to work together.... NFC, and windows reading the pairing information off it. There's something to this

Comment: Looks like Windows at least offers general support: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/nfc/pairing-bluetooth-protocol Whether a Bluetooth driver or NFC driver supports this is another story though.

Comment: @DanielB, I have no doubt that it's a supported functionality on MS's side, I just wonder if there are NFC-BT devices that implement this functionality in Windows environment, because I couldn't find a single device that explicitly says something like "...for instance, you can pair BT devices via our product".